# Jquery Validate date code failing on some browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, jquery-validate

The below code is used with Jquery Validate to check date of birth on a form.  It has worked well for years, at the turn of the year 2016/17 it failed but only in IE and Chrome, Firefox was fine.

After some investigation I could make it work using 18 as the age, not 17.  I then realized it was due to the current year being 2017 and that minus 17 is 2000.  My view is that in IE and Chrome it is using a two digit year.  A date of 01/01/00 is invalid.  The date passed in is DD/MM/YYYY.

I'm not sure how to force a four digit year to ensure this works regardless and doesn't fall over next year on 18 years.

```
> $.validator.addMethod("ValidDOB17", function (value, element) {
    // checking whether the date entered is in correct format
    var isValid = value.match(/^\d\d?\/\d\d?\/\d\d\d\d$/);
    if (isValid) {
        var today = new Date();
        var minyear = new Date();
        today.setYear(today.getYear() - 17);
        minyear.setYear(today.getYear() - 82);
        var DOB = Date.parse(value);
        if (DOB >= today || DOB <= minyear ) {
            isValid = false;
        }
        return isValid;
    }
}, "You must be aged over 17");
```

Comment: Use `.getFullYear()` rather than `.getYear()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `getFullYear()` and `setFullYear()`. The `getYear()` and `setYear()` methods are deprecated - they were made to return 2-digit years for years before 2000.

```js
var value = '01/13/2000';
var isValid = /^\d\d?\/\d\d?\/\d\d\d\d$/.test(value);

if (isValid) {
  var today = new Date();
  var minyear = new Date();
  today.setFullYear(today.getFullYear() - 17);
  minyear.setFullYear(today.getFullYear() - 82);
  var DOB = Date.parse(value);
  if (DOB >= today || DOB <= minyear) {
    isValid = false;
  }
  console.log(value + (isValid ? ' is valid' : ' is invalid'));
}
```